# Find out whether fopen(..., 'a') created a new file

Tags: php

in my PHP project, I use some kind of counter that appends to an existing (or new) file very often:

```
$f = fopen($filename, 'ab');
fwrite($f);
fclose($f);
```

When a new file is created, I have to edit this file's permissions, so another user may access the file as well:

```
$existed = file_exists($filename);
// Do the append
$f = fopen($filename, 'ab');
fwrite($f);
fclose($f);
// Update permissions
if (!$existed) {
    @chmod($filename, 0666);
}
```

Is there any way to find out, whether 'a' (append) created a new file or appended to an exiting one without using `file_exists()`? To my understanding, `file_exists()` retrieves the file stats, which causes some unnecessary overhead compared to a simple file-append. As the function is used very often, I wonder if there's an option to tell if `fopen(..., 'a')` created a new file without using `file_exists()`?

**Note:** This is mostly a question of style and interest, not a true performance issue. But if I am mistaken and `fopen()` already retrieves the file stats, please let me know!

**Update**

Okay, it really is a rather academic question. Here're some performance tests run on a windows system (Apache, Win8.1 - no UNIX file permissions) and a linux machine (Nginx, Ubuntu 14.04, virutal machine).

Each test run with 1000 repetitions, file deleted before the first repetition.

```
                                   Win    Linux
simply append one byte            1.8ms   9.4ms
append + clearstatcache()         1.8ms   9.3ms
test fileexists() + append        2.2ms  10.5ms
fileexists() + append + clear     2.2ms  11.0ms
append + chmod()                  2.7ms  12.3ms
append + fileexists() -> chmod()  3.3ms  10.6ms
```

Note: The last one is the only one that uses and IF within the test loop.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php `fopen` is just a call to the libc `fopen`, that automatically creates a file for the modes w,w+,a and a+. As far as I can see, there is no way to get the `stat` with the permission bits from the returned file pointer.

It seems that PHP stores the `stat` array for each opened file and you can access it with `fstat($fp)` with the opened file handle `$fp`. But the `mode` field contains `inode permission bits`. I can't immediately see how *"inode permission bits"* are related to the *"UNIX file mode"*. The `stat` system call does not use this term.

You can use "r+" mode to open your file and create it if that fails. If not you need to SEEK to then end to achieve something similar.

But finally it's best to check for existence before you open the file.

Answer (score 0):

No, fopen just returns the resource, it doesn't return or set a flag that indicates whether the file already existed - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: I know - I rather thought about something like `ftell()` - but that won't work with a file opened for appending only...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: see the performance test in the edited question.**

Why not calling `chmod()` every times?
Your `file_exist()` is probably (maybe a little performance test...) more expensive than a `chmod()`.

```
// Do the append
$f = fopen($filename, 'ab');
fwrite($f);
fclose($f);
// Update persmissions
@chmod($this->filename, 0666);
```

Comment: Good idea - but your hypothesis is not supported by a performance test I've run by now :)

Comment: I see that! :) Good test.